# Is an RV rental vehicle proof of accommodation for Schengen entry?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, car-rentals, proof-of-accommodation

We are four guys who have a reservation in Germany for an RV (a motor home vehicle). Will our reservation enough at immigration when we arrive, or do we have to reserve hotels?

Actually, we plan to stay in Germany for 9 days, and after we are going to Italy and France. We plan to sleep in the RV for the entire time.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need a hotel reservation to enter the Schengen area.  You need to

> justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay, and [] have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to [your] country of origin or transit to a third country into which [you] are certain to be admitted, or [be] in a position to acquire such means lawfully[.]

(Source: [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), Article 6(1)(c)).

So as long as the officers you speak to find your plan to travel and sleep in an RV credible, and that you satisfy the other conditions of entry, they will let you in.

A hotel reservation is only necessary if you plan to sleep in a hotel.

Comment: So should we go there and talk to the officers and show them the reservation of the RV and they will pass us

Comment: @MuhannaAlsharhan don't show anything unless you're specifically asked to.  If they ask what you're planning to do, say "tour in an RV."  If they ask where you're going to sleep, say "in an RV."  If they ask for proof of accommodation, show the RV reservation.  Most people get through most passport checks without showing any documents other than their passports.  If the officer decides that you're trustworthy, you don't want to take more of the officer's time than necessary by going over documents that the officer didn't ask to see.